What is the meaning of "to coin a phrase"?
What is the meaning of "to coin a phrase"?
I saw the meaning in some dictionaries and their examples, but yet I have trouble with it!
Cambridge: something you say before using an expression that has been very popular or used too much
Longman: said in a joking way when you use a very common expression, to show that you know it is used a lot
example in Longman: He’d thought the flight would never – to coin a phrase – get off the ground.
another example: I was, to coin a phrase, as sick as a parrot.
Especially in these examples, are "get off the ground" and "as sick as a parrot" the expressions that are very popular and the speakers said in joking that they know they are very common?

"To coin a phrase" really means to invent a new phrase.  We talk about words or phrases being coined:

The word "mountaineer" was coined by Shakespeare.

The use in your examples is ironic.  It is generally considered poor English to use cliches like "sick as a parrot", and "get off the ground" also has both literal and idiomatic meaning. The speaker shows that they know that the phrase has an idiomatic meaning by ironically and jokingly claiming to invent the phrase.
"Sick as a parrot" means very upset - "We were ahead 1-nil at 85 minutes but ended up losing 2-1. I was sick as a parrot".  "Get off the ground" means "start".  "To get your business off the the ground you'll need a bank loan"
Of course "to coin a phrase" is also a cliche. Generally, there is no need for an English learner to use such cliches. And this one is best avoided.

Upvoted. I can't resist pointing out (needlessly) that the claim that a word was 'invented' by Shakespeare is a rather annoying and persistent myth. The editors of OED used Shakespeare as a massive and accessible corpus of early modern English. As a result, his works are frequently the earliest example of a word being used in the dictionary. Somehow this has transmogrified into Shakespeare 'inventing' thousands of words. He did no such thing, or, at the very least, if he did, we shall never know.

@fred2 a point well made.  In early modern, "mountaineer" meant "wild mountain man" rather than professional climber, and is a borrowing from the French.  It's not recorded in Middle English, and the borrowing was probably made while Shakespeare was active, even if he wasn't the first, he was among the first.

What the OP quoted from Cambridge and Longman indeed are applicable.
In addition to those, as Collins Dictionary
says, this idiom is used

in order to show that you realize people might think that it is a silly or boring thing to say, but you think it is relevant in spite of this

That is, the speaker still wants to use the phrase but wants to avoid being seen in a similar light, silly or boring.


Coin (v)

make (coins) by stamping metal.
"guineas and half-guineas were coined"
invent or devise (a new word or phrase).
"he coined the term “desktop publishing.”"


The second definition is an analogy with the first. When you coin new currency, you make a standardized object (all US quarters are worth the same amount of money, by definition) that other people can use. So when somebody "coined a phrase", they invented a new standard phrase that other people have started using.

(The other answers are good and explain why saying this about yourself is usually sarcastic, but the verb coin meaning "to make standardized coins" is obscure and, I think, helpful for understanding the idiom)
